# How to search and count paths values in MongoDb using java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

i want to see how many documents I have in a collection with the same base path: my mongoDb is structured like this:

```
        {
            {_id:1,
             tag1: a, 
             path: C:\Users\A\Downloads\1\qwerty
            }, 
            {
            _id: 2,
            tag1: b,
            path: C:\Users\A\Downloads\2\abcd
            },
            {
             _id: 3, 
            tag1: alfa,
            path: C:\Users\A\Documents\3\fsdf
            },
            {
            _id: 4,
            tag1: beta,
            path: C:\Users\A\Documents\4\aaa
            }
        }
```

I want to search, for example, how many elements there are in C:\Users\A\Downloads and how many elements there are in C:\Users\A\Documents. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you know ahead what the _base path_ value is? For example, in the above dataset is it "C:\Users\A\Documents\"?

Comment: Yes, I know it already

Comment: I need to search for the directories inside of them

Comment: You mean search the directories in the file system?

Comment: I mean that I need to count how many documents there are with the same base path

Comment: I posted the Java code for counting for both the base paths:  `C:\Users\A\Downloads` and `C:\Users\A\Documents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to see how many documents I have in a collection with the same
>   base path:

Assuming you are supplying the *base path* to find the number of documents with that base path - the following [regex query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html) will count all the documents with the `path` field value staring with "C:\Users\A\Downloads\".

```
db.paths.find( { path: /^C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\/ } ).count()
```

**Code Using MongoDB Java Driver:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Documents\\\\");
Bson queryFilter = regex("path", p);
long count = collection.countDocuments(filter);
```

---

The following is the data I am using; there are 4 documents. When I run the code I get a *count of 2* (which is correct and expected as there are two paths which match the pattern "^C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\").

[image]

---

Using the same data as shown in the Compass screenshot, the following aggregation

```
db.paths.aggregate( [
  { 
      $group : { 
          _id :  "Counts", 
          Documents: { 
              $sum: {
                  $cond: [ { $regexMatch: { input: "$path" , regex: /^C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\/ } }, 1, 0 ]
              } 
          },
          Downloads: { 
              $sum: {
                  $cond: [ { $regexMatch: { input: "$path" , regex: /^C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\/ } }, 1, 0 ]
              } 
          }
      }
  },
] )
```

prints:

```
{ "_id" : "Counts", "Documents" : 2, "Downloads" : 1 }
```

The **Java code** for the above aggregation:

```
Pattern docPattern = Pattern.compile("^C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Documents\\\\");
Pattern downloadPattern = Pattern.compile("^C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Downloads\\\\");

List<Bson> pipeline = 
    Arrays.asList(new Document("$group",
        new Document("_id", "Counts")
            .append("document_counts",
                new Document("$sum",
                    new Document("$cond",
                        Arrays.asList(
                            new Document("$regexMatch", 
                                new Document("input", "$path")
                                    .append("regex", docPattern)),
                            1L, 0L
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .append("download_counts",
                new Document("$sum",
                    new Document("$cond",
                        Arrays.asList(
                            new Document("$regexMatch", 
                                new Document("input", "$path")
                                    .append("regex", downloadPattern)),
                            1L, 0L
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        project(excludeId())
    );

List<Document> results = new ArrayList<>();
collection.aggregate(pipeline).into(results); 

results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The result document:

```
Document{ { document_counts=2, download_counts=1 } }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using the java driver and it send me an error saying 'Regular expression is invalid: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u' so I can't search for '\Users'

Comment: This doesn't work for me. it says that there is nothing

Comment: Using your sample document from the post I was able to count correctly - the documents with the `path` field value starting with "C:\Users\A\Documents\". I am using MongoDB v4.2 and Java driver v3.9.

Comment: Strange, it doesn't seem to exist any "regex" method

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel stupid, I was looking for the wrong regex method.

Comment: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Documents\\\\");
        Bson queryFilter = Filters.regex("path", p);
        long count = collection.countDocuments(queryFilter);`
Doing like this it returns me 0

Comment: Can you try with the regex pattern `"^C"` (instead of `"^C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Documents\\\\"`) and see what is happening.

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice that there are two patterns: `C:\Users\A\Downloads` and `Documents`. The solution requires Aggregation and grouping; I will post more code. But, meanwhile, please see if the count for one pattern (as in the sample I am using) is working for you also.

Comment: I also, added code to count for the two patterns: `C:\Users\A\Downloads\` and `C:\Users\A\Documents\`. Once, you confirm the aggregation works fine, I can convert it into Java code.